# Maven: building a submodule which is itself a multi-module

Tags: maven

Project `top` is a multi-module project, referring to modules `middle-1`, `middle-2` and `middle-3`.

Project `middle-1` is itself a multi-module project, containing `bottom-1`, `bottom-2` and `bottom-3`.

`bottom-1` depends on `middle-2`.

Like this:

```
top
|
|- middle-1
|  |
|  |- bottom-1
|  |- bottom-2
|  |- bottom-3
|
|- middle-2
|- middle-3
```

I want to build `middle-1`, with all of its submodules, as well all of their dependencies. Namely, I want the reactor to build:

- `middle-1`
- `middle-1\bottom-1`
- `middle-1\bottom-2`
- `middle-1\bottom-3`
- `middle-2` (because `bottom-1` depends on it)

I was surprised to find out that this command:

```
mvn clean package -pl middle-1 -am
```

Doesn't work. It only builds the top-level `middle-1`, completely avoiding its submodules.

In other words, looks like `-pl` doesn't drill down into the specified projects' submodules.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for?

Comment: What does it mean: `Doesn't work.` ? Error message? Do you have an example project ? Does you have `middle-2` child modules? So based on your setup I would ask: Why not building `mvn clean package -pl bottom-1 -amd`?

Comment: @khmarbaise, I mentioned it in the question: "It only builds the top-level middle-1, completely avoiding its submodules." Also, my question was more about the principle rather than my isolated use case: why doesn't `-pl` drill down into sub-submodules (maybe it's a bug?), and how to achieve it anyway.

Comment: The module `middle-1´ is a parent which has the packaging `pom` which is built correctly and has no dependencies. Furthermore `-pl` stands for a one or more projects to built without using the usual reactor.. how to achieve it I already gave a suggestion.

Comment: @Isaac - did you find a solution? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Dikla — I didn't. I'm pretty sure this is by design.

Comment: @Isaac - Too bad. Thanks!